# Does anyone have experiance with Rally and Rational Team Concert, can you compare the two packages

Tags: migration, rally, rtc, agile-project-management

My company has a rather extensive Rally implementation but I just heard a rumor that they are looking into moving to Rational Team Concert.

Does anyone have any experience with both platforms?  I am concerned that RTC is designed and implemented with a classic waterfall development mindset with "Agile Looking" bolt-ons as opposed to an Agile from the ground up product like Rally.

Also, what are the integrations like with Eclipse, Quality Center, Git Hub.

To be honest I have never even seen RTC but I am really concerned that it will be sold to upper management and not be as capable a product as Rally to meet our needs.  I am also concerned about the migration between the two if it comes to that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience in Rally, but do in RTC.

RTC doesn't come with one pre-defined model, but with "Process Configuration" that you can adapt/rename/amend to your specific way of working. In that, it is very nimble.
It certainly has moved away from the sole "Maturity Model" reference in this [Rally article](http://www.rallydev.com/community/agile-blog/does-agile-need-its-own-process-maturity-model) (2009).

The planning aspect might be a bit more limited than in Rally, but it is possible, *in theory* to replicate most of them.

Answer (score 1):

Some comments regarding integration that VonC didn't comment on.

**Eclipse**

There's an Eclipseplugin that provides the user with full functionality, even more functionality than the webinterface. So the user gets full access to all data in RTC. Beware that there is no integration to Eclipse Mylyn, if you want that (which you should want) you will have to buy a separate product from [Tasktop](http://tasktop.com/connectors/ibm-rtc/sync)

**Quality Center**

No natural integration, but several alternatives exists: (sync-based) [CM Logic JazzConnect](http://www.cm-logic.com/jazzconnect-hpqc-rtc.html), [Kovair Omnibus](http://www.kovair.com/omnibus-solutions/index.html), [Tasktop Sync](http://tasktop.com/sync), [BSD Sync](http://www.bsdgroupinc.com/qcrtc.php) and (non-sync-based) [IBM Rational Lifecycle Adapter](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/offers/lp/demos/summary/r-using-ibm-rational-team-concert-hp-alm-1.html) which is [OSLC-based](http://open-services.net).

**Git Hub**

No personal experience, but some kind of integration between Git and RTC, or rather OSLC, exists. [See article](https://jazz.net/library/article/854)